# Django_Filters :no need to show all items using object.all() at the first load

Tags: django, django-filter

I am new for Django_Filter

As I notice, django_filter always loads all objects on the firs loading despite not filtered yet. Due to a large amount of data in the table in the database. So it results in poor performance for loading all objects unnecessarily.

***it is rather unreasonable in my view. Thus the better way, it should filter a result whenever click button only.***

***How to set Django_Filter  in order to show the result when only click the search button(I don't want to list all items by using objects.all()).***

These are my code related to this problem

model.py

```
from django.db import models
class Product_Type(models.Model):
    productype_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Inventory(models.Model):
   serial_number=models.CharField('Serial Number',max_length=50)
   product_type=models.ForeignKey( Product_Type,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Product Type')
```

filter.py

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import *
from app.models import *

class  InventoriesForCopy_Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):

  class Meta:
       model=Inventory
       fields=['product_type','serial_number']
```

views.py

```
def list_inventory_for_copy(request, proj_id):

   inventories_all = Inventory.objects.all()
   xfilter = InventoriesForCopy_Filter(request.GET, queryset=inventories_all)
   inventories = xfilter.qs
   context = {'project_id': proj_id, 'xfilter': xfilter, 'inventories': inventories}

   return render(request, 'app/inventory_add_copy.html', context)
```

inventory_add_copy.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if messages %}
    <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li><strong>{{ message }}</strong></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
<form method="get">
    {{xfilter.form}}
     <button  type="submit">Get Inventories</button>
</form>
Create Inventory for Project ID : {{ project_id }}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>SerialNo</td>
        <td>ProductType</td>

    </tr>
    {% for item in inventories %}
        <tr>

            <td>{{ item.serial_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.product_type }}</td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

The picture below describes itself:
[image]

Comment: You can  override what `all()` returns by writing your own `get_queryset` method.

Comment: And you're explicitly calling `all` and then filtering the results, so yes - you'll get all objects returned. If you don't want this, I suggest you use `.filter()` instead of `.all()`